# Using Artistic Effects on Shapes in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When arranging elements on my PowerPoint slides, I have one slide where I would like to use the pencil grayscale effect found under artistic effects. While I can use this for pictures, I cannot use it for shapes that I created in PowerPoint. Is there any way to replicate artistic effects on shapes without exporting the shapes as images from other programs, then adding them back in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that Powerpoint Artistic Effects are designed for bitmap images only, whereas shapes will be a vector based format.

Other than saving out the shapes as bitmaps and re-importing them like you suggested, I don't think this will be achievable.

Comment: That makes sense, although it's unfortunate. It's difficult to create a uniform presentation with that approach.